# python multiprocessing stuck (maybe reading csv)

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I am trying to learn how to use `multiprocessing` and I am having a problem.

I am trying to run this code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import random
import string

random.seed(123)

# Define an output queue
output = mp.Queue()

# define a example function
def rand_string(length, output):
    """ Generates a random string of numbers, lower- and uppercase chars. """
    rand_str = ''.join(random.choice(
                        string.ascii_lowercase
                        + string.ascii_uppercase
                        + string.digits)
                   for i in range(length))
    output.put(rand_str)

# Setup a list of processes that we want to run
processes = [mp.Process(target=rand_string, args=(5, output)) for x in range(4)]

# Run processes
for p in processes:
    p.start()

# Exit the completed processes
for p in processes:
    p.join()

# Get process results from the output queue
results = [output.get() for p in processes]

print(results)
```

From [here](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html)

The code in itself runs properly, but when I replace `rand_string` with my function (reads a bunch of csv files in Pandas dataframes) the code never ends.

The function is this:

```
def readMyCSV(clFile):

    aClTable = pd.read_csv(clFile)

    # I do some processing here, but at the end the 
    # function returns a Pandas DataFrame

    return(aClTable)
```

Then I wrap the function so that it allows for a `Queue` in the arguments:

```
def readMyCSVParWrap(clFile, outputq):
    outputq.put(readMyCSV(clFile))
```

and I build the processes with:

```
processes = [mp.Process(target=readMyCSVParWrap, args=(singleFile,output)) for singleFile in allFiles[:5]]
```

If I do so, the code never stops running, and results are never printed.

IF I put only the clFile string in the output queue, e.g.:

```
outputq.put((clFile))
```

the results are printed properly (just a list of clFiles)

When I look at `htop`, I see 5 processes being spawn, but they do not use any CPU.

Lastly, the `readMyCSV` function works properly if I run it by itself (returns a `Pandas` DataFrame)

Is there anything I am doing wrong? 
I am running this in a Jupyter notebook, maybe that is an issue?

Comment: Your `readMyCSVParWrap` takes three arguments but you're passing only two when you build the processes. Also in `readMyCSVParWrap` your parameter is `cellFile`but you are passing `clFile` to `readMyCSV`.

Comment: You are right. I modified the example to make it simpler and forgot to edit unnecessary stuff. I will edit the post to make it correct.
However, even after corrections it doesn't work.

Comment: Seems like you're deadlocking, try removing the joins.

Comment: then I am lost :D
All the "how to do parallel with python" searches take me to something that has start and join.

Never mind, I just read your other answer.

Comment: then swap join and queue.get, see the answer

Answer (score 1):

Seems your `join`-statements on the processes are causing a deadlock. The processes can't terminate because they wait till the items on the queue are consumed, but in your code this happens only after the joining.

> Joining processes that use queues
>
> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. (The child process can call the Queue.cancel_join_thread method of the queue to avoid this behaviour.)
>
> This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure that processes which have put items on the queue will terminate. Remember also that non-daemonic processes will be joined automatically.
>   [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html)

The docs further suggest to swap the lines with `queue.get` and `join` or just removing `join`.

Also important:

> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process)...protect the “entry point” of the program by using if **name** == '**main**':. [ibid](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: I will try to invert those two lines, and report what happens. Thanks!

Comment: @mic Famous last words? ;)